# Can Windows Event Viewer be read using VBA code?

Tags: vba, event-viewer

I want to be able to read Windows Event Viewer items from VBA code (such as when a user has logged on or off their workstation)

Comment: There is [Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/reading-from-the-event-log) to read from the event log. VBA can use Windows API. [Therefore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism), VBA can read the Windows event log.

Comment: Thanks, GSerg, but the only example code I can find is C or C++, I need to see some samples using VBA

Comment: Take the C or C++ example code, see what functions are called, read the documentation on them, [declare](http://www.activevb.de/rubriken/apiviewer/index-apiviewereng.html) them in VBA and port the logic appropriately.

Comment: I don't see how that's going to work to use VBA code to get the instances when a user has logged into the computer

Answer (score 2):

I've downloaded a code sample more than a decade ago from somewhere. Unfortunately I can't provide the author's name or the source to give credit where credit is due. The following is the module encapsulating the Event log reading. It's been part of a sample project, which I uploaded [here](http://tools.basicaware.de/downloads/eventlogreader.zip) so you can see how to use the module. It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it should give you a decent start.

```
Option Explicit


Private Const EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ = &H1
Private Const EVENTLOG_SEEK_READ = &H2
Private Const EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ = &H4
Private Const EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ = &H8

Private Type EVENTLOGRECORD
     Length As Long               'Length of full record
     Reserved As Long             'Used by the service
     RecordNumber As Long         'Absolute record number
     TimeGenerated As Long        'Seconds since 1-1-1970
     TimeWritten As Long          'Seconds since 1-1-1970
     EventID As Long
     EventType As Integer
     NumStrings As Integer
     EventCategory As Integer
     ReservedFlags As Integer     'For use with paired events (auditing)
     ClosingRecordNumber As Long  'For use with paired events (auditing)
     StringOffset As Long         'Offset from beginning of record
     UserSidLength As Long
     UserSidOffset As Long
     DataLength As Long
     DataOffset As Long           'Offset from beginning of record
End Type

Private Declare Sub CopyMem Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (dst As Any, src As Any, ByVal Size As Long)
Private Declare Function OpenEventLog Lib "advapi32" Alias "OpenEventLogA" (ByVal lpUNCServerName As String, ByVal lpEventSourceName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseEventLog Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hEventLog As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetNumberOfEventLogRecords Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hEventLog As Long, NumberOfRecords As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ReadEventLog Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "ReadEventLogA" (ByVal hEventLog As Long, ByVal dwReadFlags As Long, ByVal dwRecordOffset As Long, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nNumberOfBytesToRead As Long, pnBytesRead As Long, pnMinNumberOfBytesNeeded As Long) As Long

Public Function ReadEvents(ByVal ServerName As String, ByVal EventType As String) As String
    'Returns the eventlog content as a vbcrlf separated string
    Dim ret As Long, EventLogHwd As Long, EvtRecNo As Long, rBytesRead As Long, rBytesNeeded As Long
    Dim rBuff As EVENTLOGRECORD, EvtReadFlags As Long
    Dim eBuff() As Byte, StrucLen As Long, EvtRecLen As Long
    Dim strBuffer As String, strStart As Long, strStop As Long, strCount As Long, eBytePointer As Long
    Dim eSourceName As String, eComputerName As String, ThisString As String

    Dim tmpString As String

    StrucLen = Len(rBuff)
    ReDim eBuff(16384)
    EvtReadFlags = EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ Or EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ

    EventLogHwd = OpenEventLog(ServerName, EventType)
    If EventLogHwd = 0 Then Exit Function

    ret = GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(EventLogHwd, EvtRecNo)
    If ret = 0 Then Exit Function

    Do While rBuff.RecordNumber < EvtRecNo
        'Reads all events in 16K chunks
        ret = ReadEventLog(EventLogHwd, EvtReadFlags, rBuff.RecordNumber + 1, eBuff(0), 16384, rBytesRead, rBytesNeeded)
        If ret = 0 Then Exit Function

        eBytePointer = 0
        Do While eBytePointer < rBytesRead
            CopyMem rBuff, eBuff(eBytePointer), StrucLen
            EvtRecLen = rBuff.Length
            'Here rBuff is already filled, then we can filter events

            strBuffer = Space(EvtRecLen - StrucLen)
            CopyMem ByVal strBuffer, eBuff(StrucLen + eBytePointer), (EvtRecLen - StrucLen)
            eBytePointer = eBytePointer + EvtRecLen

            strStart = 1
            strStop = InStr(strStart, strBuffer, Chr(0))
            eSourceName = Mid(strBuffer, strStart, strStop - strStart)

            strStart = strStop + 1
            strStop = InStr(strStart, strBuffer, Chr(0))
            eComputerName = Mid(strBuffer, strStart, strStop - strStart)

            'Put all strings together, we can parse later...
            If rBuff.NumStrings > 0 Then
                strStart = rBuff.StringOffset - StrucLen + 1
                ThisString = ""
                For strCount = 1 To rBuff.NumStrings
                    strStop = InStr(strStart, strBuffer, Chr(0))
                    ThisString = ThisString & Mid(strBuffer, strStart, strStop - strStart) & " "
                    strStart = strStop + 1
                Next strCount
                'Here 'ThisString' contains all strings of the current event
                If Len(tmpString) > 0 Then
                    tmpString = tmpString & vbCrLf
                End If
                tmpString = tmpString & "(Source: " & eSourceName & ") " & ThisString


            End If
        Loop
    Loop

    ret = CloseEventLog(EventLogHwd)

    ReadEvents = tmpString

End Function
```

Comment: OK thanks Hel, that looks like it will give me a big jump start, thanks!